# Categorized Data for Deep Learning

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I want to create deep learning neural network to recognize opinion in text. Is there any database where I can find categorized text sets so I could use it to feed my neural network? Can you provide me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

- Have a look at: [Open Data for Deep Learning](https://skymind.ai/wiki/open-datasets) : Around 50 datasets.
- Kaggle Deep Learning Competitions:

  [Digit Recognizer](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer)
     [Facial Keypoints Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection)
     [Grasp-and-Lift EEG Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/grasp-and-lift-eeg-detection)
     [Diabetic Retinopathy Detection](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection)
     [National Data Science Bowl](https://www.kaggle.com/c/datasciencebowl)
     [Right Whale Recognition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/noaa-right-whale-recognition)